# How to change where EntityFrameworkCore migrations are stored?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I know this is that type of question that was asked before but I couldn't find a valid answer to it.

So, is there a possibility to change where migrations are stored? I'm using EF Core.

*FYI: I know that if you move the first generated migration, the upcoming ones will be placed in the same location.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For core EF projects, you can specify the output directory with the '-o' or '--output-dir' option after Add-Migration.

Example:

```
Add-Migration -o Data\Migrations
```

If using the dotnet core CLI command, you can specify the same option:

```
dotnet ef migrations add -o Data\Migrations
```

Sources and more info:

- https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/powershell.html
- https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html

Comment: Great answer. Worked like a charm.